# Python Type Error when setting up pagination in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

Hi I am following the official documentation and setting up pagination for my website, my index template looks like this;

```
{% for post in list_of_posts %}
<div class="body"><a class="title" href="/post/{{post.id}}"><h2>{{ post.title }}</h2></a>
<P>{{ post.body|truncatewords:50|wordwrap:110 }}</P>    
<h3>{{ post.date|date:"jS F Y" }}</h3>
<hr>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if post.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ post.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
            Page {{ post.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if post.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ post.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

and my view looks like this;

```
# Main page
def index(request):
list_of_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
list_of_posts = list_of_posts.filter(published=True)
paginator = Paginator(list_of_posts, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    post = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    post = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    post = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response('index.html', {'list_of_posts': list_of_posts})
```

I get a stange feeling the TypeError is due to the paginator not outputting any value? My traceback isnt too helpful but here it is

```
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py in        validate_number, line 23
TypeError at /
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Any guidance on what could be going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, please, please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 4):

Add TypeError in your first catch:

```
except (PageNotAnInteger, TypeError):
    # ...
```

But you also could avoid this error if you will get page number like this:

```
page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
```

Comment: Also, it could be that somehow `paginator.num_pages` is not a valid number for some reason.

Comment: For shame! Nobody fixed this yet? Took all of ten minutes to patch!  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18421

Comment: OK, if you follow the link to my patch, you'll see this is already fixed in Django 1.4. This seems to be a 1.3 issue.

Answer (score 0):

The body of your view function isn't indented.  Is that just how it came out on this page?

Also, it shouldn't avoid the error, but it looks like you're not sending the post variable to the template (instead of list_of_posts).

Lastly, do you have this at the top of your module ...

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a small code for `pagination` here Hope It will helps You:

```
def pagination(request, list_of_posts, result_per_page):
    paginator = Paginator(list_of_posts, result_per_page)
    try: // **Most probably here your code is doing somthing wrong**.
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return posts
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a statement code for pagination here. I Hope It will help You

```
if str(page) > str(paginator.num_pages):
        page = paginator.num_pages
```